# XML Serialization: Simplification

Tags: android, xml, rss, xmlserializer

I have recently started working on an Android application which acts as an RSS Reader.

At the moment, the application identifies an rss url from the website and parses the XML file for specific data to display in a List View. By opening one of the items/articles on the listview, the application opens in WebView.

To me, webview doesn't seem to really cut it. So instead, I want to use the data that I obtain from the RSS XML and be able to display it on a different Layout. Basically have the title and description of the article to begin with.

I'm a little lost as I don't understand a lot of the programming terminology and I did do several searches on how to tackle this problem. So out of curiousity, is XML Serialization what I should be looking for or trying to implement in my code?
If not, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

So you have the title and description of the article? if you want to display it on different layout, you could make a second activity for displaying the layout, then pass the title and description from the previous activity by using `Bundle`. For googling, you might look for "Passing data activity android"